# Toast Alert Dialog is not displaying in ListView

Tags: android

I wrote an Application in which we can add items to the list view..i'm doing validation for that if any one making the same entry it should display an alert

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Serial No Already Exist..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

But it not displaying while I'm running on emulator. I'm sure that my validation code is correct.

Comment: Asta ka pasta :D you forget to append `.Show()` at the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Serial No Already Exist..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

add the show() to the toast like this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Serial No Already Exist..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You need to specify show() to make the toast visible

Answer (score 2):

Everything is perfect except one that you forget to append `.Show()` at the end, and also check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) .

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Serial No Already Exist..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).Show();
```

Instead#

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Serial No Already Exist..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```